# Getting full list of facebook friends through graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have IOS app for that login is through Facebook, For some feature I need full list of friends.
With current version of Graph API calling "me/friends" only returns person's friends who also use the app.
So now getting full friends list not at all possible or is there any way to get full list.
Also I need to invite my friends to use the app.

Note: App is not a Game app.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you're using a v2.0 app, there's no other way to get all friends. Maybe if you give some detail about the feature which needs all friends, there could be some other functionality to fulfill your usecase

Comment: Features like grouping FB friends, selecting some friends for some task etc. those friends may not be app users.

Comment: I guess then you'll have difficulties... Unfortunately FB doesn't want this functionality anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the earlier comments on this question might tell you, this is **100% possible** with the [`me/taggable friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) endpoint in Graph v2.0.

**However** there are three things worth noting:

1. Facebook is strict on the usage of this endpoint, so you'll need to get your use of it approved by the review team.
2. Taggable friends can only be used in the context of "friends you're about to tag on Facebook.com". This endpoint cannot be used for any other purpose.
3. When you query `me/taggable_friends`, the id returned for each user is NOT their Facebook id. It is a short-lived token that can be passed via the API to instruct Facebook to tag that user.